# Check powershell version and run a function based on the version

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to check the powershell version and based on what version, I need to run a specific function due to command and syntax differences between the different versions. I'm trying to create a variable with only the version number in it for easy comparison. Here's the code.

```
$PSversion = {$PSVersionTable.PSVersion | sort-object major | ForEach-Object     {$_.major}}

Switch ($PSversion) {
    2 {V2}
    4 {V4}
    5 {V5}
}

function V2 {
    "You have Powershell Version 2"
}

function V4 {
    "You have Powershell Version 4"
}

function V5 {
    "You have Powershell Version 5"
}
```

When I run the script it returns a blank line, when I print out the contents of the variable, I get the number and a new line. I've tried using replace to get rid of the new line but it's always there. If I enter the variable command directly into a powershell window, then print out the contents of the variable, I get the version number only, no new line. If I run the script from the same powershell window, I get nothing.

[image]

Any help on this would be appreciated! I don't have to use this method, any method to check the powershell version and run a function based on the version is all I'm looking for.

Comment: Move the `switch` statement to _after_ the functions have been defined

Comment: Also an improvement: `Switch ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major)`

Comment: General comment on this approach: it is better to check whether specific property, function or whatever exist than presuming it based on the version. I also recomment you to have a look at the [`#Requires`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_requires?view=powershell-5.1) directive.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In addition to @MathiasRJesson's comment about moving the functions to before they're being used, you're assigning a scriptblock to the `$PSversion` variable.  It's not evaluating it.

This:

```
$PSversion = {$PSVersionTable.PSVersion | sort-object major | ForEach-Object     {$_.major}}
```

Should be:

```
$PSversion = $PSVersionTable.PSVersion | sort-object major | ForEach-Object     {$_.major}
```

Or could be just:

```
$PSversion = $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Getting the whole Powershell version
$version = (Get-Host | Select-Object Version).Version

# Only the major one
$majvers = $version.Major

# The full version number (as a string)
$verstr = $version.toString()
```